# the application requires the latest version of ARcore ? what does this means?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I installed the android sdk and selected the correct path and also the jdk 1.8.0_152 but i don't know why the app is not running.Is this because my android version in the phone is Nougat 7.0 or something else .

Comment: What Android device are you using?

Comment: @Programmer Redmi Note 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device is not listed as supported by the official ARCore. On some Nougat devices, you can try [this hack](https://youtube.com/watch?v=D1uEaaxJOXQ), but there may be some [problems specific to Redmi Note 4](https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all/issues/4).